# What is the path of 'navit.xml' file in Raspberry Pi

Tags: path, navigation, raspberry-pi, raspbian, navit

I am trying to configure Navit om my RaspberryPi but I can't find navit.xml to change. Everybody tell navit.xml file should be chanced to configuration on the internet but no one says where it is.

Where is the navit.xml in RaspberryPi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default location for the navit.xml file is in

```
/etc/navit/navit.xml
```

I would highly recommend you copy that file to

```
~/.navit/navit.xml
```

so that it is easier to find, navit will then use that one in your home directory.